# Could someone help me to validate dynamic value in first row first column compared to the second row first column in selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium

help me how to validate dynamic value in first row first column is updated when compared to the second row first column in selenium c#.
Table has even and odd rows.

Comment: If you will add some code example and your tries, we will be able to help you and you will follow the guidelines for posting correct question

Comment: I have added my code.Could you suggest me if my approach is correct or should I add more efficient way? I would like to use > operator but not sure how to use that in this context.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I need to compare the second occurrence value with first occurrence value and make sure the first(latest) occurrence value is incremented correctly.Here is my approach

public bool? ValidateProposalIncrement(string offer)
        {

```
        Thread.Sleep(1500);
        IWebElement offerName = WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("\r\n//*[@id=\"data\"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]"));
        string offer_name = offerName.Text;
        IWebElement latestOfferId = WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//a[contains(.,'XYZ')])[1]/parent::*/preceding-sibling::td[3][last()]"));
        String latest_offerId = latestOfferId.Text;
        IWebElement oldOfferId = WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//a[contains(.,'XYZ')])[2]/parent::*/preceding-sibling::td[3][last()]"));
        String old_offerId = oldOfferId.Text;
        if (offerName.Contains(offer) && latestOfferId != oldOfferId)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
```